# How to call images from your plugins image folder?

Tags: plugin-development, urls, plugins-url

I've done a lot of research and learned a lot about WP constants and function usage for getting image paths etc. but still my original problem persists.

```
<img src="<?PHP echo WP_PLUGIN_DIR . 'vertical-social-buttons/images/facebook.png'?>">

<img src="<?PHP echo WP_PLUGIN_DIR . 'vertical-social-buttons/images/facebook.png'?>">

<img src="<?PHP echo plugins_url('vertical-social-buttons/images/facebook.png', __FILE__);?>">
```

All give me broken images. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128873/how-to-get-the-current-plugin-directory-in-wordpress

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`plugin_dir_url()`](http://queryposts.com/function/plugin_dir_url/) to get the public URI for the directory where the calling PHP file is.

```
<img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'images/facebook.png'; ?>">
```

If the PHP file is in a sub directory of your plugin you have to go up:

```
<img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . 'images/facebook.png'; ?>">
```